# How to define constructor signature in interface?

Tags: java, c#, node.js, typescript

Below is the question regarding defining constructor signature in TypeScript interface (Javascript), though in the end it turned to be not available. However, this is possible in objective-c and that's it would be nice to have that elsewhere too.

I have a set of data object classes and all of them will be used through a common constructor with json string argument. As I picked TypeScript as a tool which has a compiler and will help me to find mistakes and problems earlier, how could I define a constructor in interface and then implement it in the class?

```
interface IParsable {

  //constructor(json : string);
  new (json : string);
}

class UserObject implements IParsable {

constructor(json : string) {

   //...
}
```

The code works but compiler shows me error "error TS2420: Class 'UserObject' incorrectly implements interface 'IParsable'." If I use "constructor" instead of new in interface then I get "Method constructor from interaface IParsable is not implemented".

**UPDATE**: In objective-c, an object could be created using two approaches:

**First approach**:

```
UserObject *userObject = [[UserObject alloc] init];
```

The creation of an object consist of two methods. Alloc - allocates needed memory and init is default constructor name. Constructors are just like regular methods in objective-c and have their names. Therefore, if you need to have a custom constructor with parameters then you just define a new method, for example initWithJson:(NSString *)json. Therefore you can define anything you want in the interface and enforce the contract.

**Second approach**:

```
UserObject *userObject = [UserObject new];
```

new is a reserved word, however it actually performs alloc + init and you can't use your custom constructor. Therefore a recommended way is to use alloc + init, so that you can always replace it with your custom constructor method like alloc + initWithJson if you need.

As it turns out, there's no way how to do this even in java or C#. I always thought these  languages are a lot more standard and well thought in terms of OOP, though this little thing is better done in objective-c.

Comment: What use would there be in having an interface define a constructor?

Comment: What use is in having a compiler? It's a tool which helps you and your teammates to spot mistakes faster. Also, always use an interface as a  contract for all of the classes which will implement that. A  constructor is just a method like all other methods. In all my projects in objective-c, I was able to define common things in interface, including constructor signature. It's strange I need to present arguments for such an obvious thing

Comment: I'm struggeling with a similar problem since days. The example from TypeScript handbook doesn't work and I guess it's a bug in TypeScript compiler. I already created an issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8917

Answer (score 1):

An `extends` clause defines the behavior of an *instance* of a class, not its *constructor function*. Constructors themselves are not part of the *instance* of a class. Basically, you're saying that an *instance* of `UserObject` (the result of calling `new` on it) can itself be invoked `new`, which is not the case:

```
var x = new UserObject();
var y = new x(); // Nonsense, of course
```

There currently is no direct syntax in TypeScript to indicate that the constructor function `UserObject` matches the interface `IParsable`. You can use this as a workaround:

```
class UserObject { ... }
UserObject === <IParsable>undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is structurally typed, so you can get all the checking you want without actually needing to use the`implements` keyword on a class.

In the example below, the arguments passed to the constructor of an `IParsable` are checked (within the `example` function). You also cannot pass an argument to the `example` function that doesn't satisfy the `IParsable` interface, i.e. it must accept a string argument (or no argument at all).

I have highlighted three errors that the compiler will catch.

```
interface IParsable {
    new (json: string);
}

class ExampleOne {
    constructor(json: string) {

    }
}

class ExampleTwo {
    constructor(json: string) {

    }
}

class ExampleThree {
    constructor(arg: number) {

    }
}

function example(obj: IParsable) {
    // Error - doesn't pass string arg
    //return new obj();

    // Error - wrong argument type
    //return new obj(1);

    return new obj('{ a: "b"}');

}

example(ExampleOne);
example(ExampleTwo);

// Error - Doesn't satisfy IParsable
//example(ExampleThree);
```

Comment: I'm not very strong in javascript, therefore I want to use TypeScript which will allow me to use standard OOP features and write classical code. Regarding your example, could you change it so it would look like more regular code with classes? Currently, I don't understand why example is just a plain function (not class) and why we pass class name directly to example function. I'm trying to write a code where I define class, its constructor, then create class object using new.

Comment: The function was just "an example of how the compiler will check your types". The key concept is that you are now working in a structural type system and it is different to a nominal type system.